# How to set weight of tablerows elements?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout which I add rows programmatically and I'm trying to set "weight" of elements contained in rows programmatically.

I'm trying to do that by setting `weightSum` on the TableRow and setting "weight" of the columns using the last parameter of "LayoutParams", but nothing appears; instead if I give a fixed width to elements, code works well.

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sample);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tr.setWeightSum(1f);

        TableRow.LayoutParams lp;
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
        lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.6f);
        tv1.setText("AAA");
        tv1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
        lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.4f);
        tv2.setText("BBB");
        tv2.setLayoutParams(lp);

        tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: to set the LayoutParams of the TableRow use TableLayout.LayoutParams..

Comment: yes now it works, I dont know why i didnt see it... thank you

Answer (score 6):

Here is the updated code for setting the weightsum and column weight programmatically for a tableLayout.

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sample);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tr.setWeightSum(4); //total row weight

TableRow.LayoutParams lp;
lp.weight = 1; //column weight
TextView tv1 = new TextView(getActivity());
lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.6f);
tv1.setText("AAA");
tv1.setLayoutParams(lp);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.4f);
tv2.setText("BBB");
tv2.setLayoutParams(lp);

tr.addView(tv1);
tr.addView(tv2);
tl.addView(tr);
```